# How to confine WINE apps using a chroot jail?

Tags: gnome, wine, security, virtualization, chroot

I have read the [SecuringWine](http://wiki.winehq.org/SecuringWine) page on WINE official website, and one of the things it says you can do to increase security is:

> One can run wine inside a chroot jail.

So what exactly is a "chroot jail"? And how do I set it up with WINE apps? I am running WINE 1.7 on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113/58485)

> "chroot jail" is a misnomer [...]

and

> `chroot` is not intended to force a program to stay in that simulated filesystem; a program that knows it's in a `chroot` "jail" can fairly easily escape, so you shouldn't use chroot as a security measure to prevent a program from modifying files outside your simulated filesystem

Indeed, it is just a normal `chroot` with the hope that what you are doing does not get out of it.

If you are still motivated to use it, you can follow the [official Ubuntu Documentation on `chroot`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot) to start understanding and setting it.

And you can then obviously come back to AskUbuntu if you have specific questions. :)