# How to confine "unconfined" apps?

Tags: software-installation, software-center, security

Suppose one is installing an "unconfined" app (e. g. Slack) via Ubuntu's Software. Unless extra measures are taken, the app is said to have access to all the contents of the home directory.

Is there a way to "confine" such apps? As far as I understood, [chroot jail won't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706296/how-to-confine-wine-apps-using-a-chroot-jail).
Will [AppArmor](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AppArmor) do the job? Or [Firejail](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firejail)? Or should I look into some other direction?

Thanks.

P. S. I'm currently using Ubuntu 19.10, if that matters.

Comment: Maybe as a temporary solution it is possible to run the browser alternatives of those apps, or have a virtual machine. But I really hope there is a better way

Answer (score 1):

There are many options to confine a software in Linux, but it depends if it is a `deb` package or a `snap`.

### Slack Debian Package

If you have installed the [Debian package of Slack](https://slack.com/intl/en-tr/downloads/linux?eu_nc=1), you can go with `firejail` as it already has a default profile for confinement ([see the profile](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/blob/master/etc/slack.profile)).

- To install and use `firejail` to confine Slack `deb` package:

```
sudo apt-get install firejail firejail-profiles
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/firejail /usr/local/bin/<application>
```

Replace `<application>` with the name of Slack binary in `/usr/bin`. The second line creates a symbolic link for the software-to-be-sanboxed to run under firejail.

- Add your username to `/etc/firejail/firejail.users`, one line per username.
- Open Slack, and check if the confinement works via: `firejail --tree`.

You can check the default Slack profile in your system via: `cat /etc/firejail/slack.profile`. If you are curios about what each line does, check out the `firejail.profile` [man page](https://firejail.wordpress.com/features-3/man-firejail-profile/).

### Slack Snap package

Snaps are different, and (might) have built-in [confinement system](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement) using kernel namespaces, apparmor and seccomp. However, the Slack package is installed via `sudo snap install slack --classic`, and the `--classic` flag here tells that there will be no strict confinement.
Depending on the `firejail` version you install, you might get `snap` support with a default firejail profile, but [the firejail release notes](https://firejail.wordpress.com/download-2/release-notes/) shows that the support for snap packages were dropped in 0.9.60.

### References

- https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/
- https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement

Comment: I still didn't have the time to study your response. But thanks a lot for sharing! Hopefully in the future I will.